# Which one better to use shortuuid or uuid?

Tags: python, uuid

Python:

Just out of curosity I was thinking that combinations which uuid4 or uuid6 can provide - shortuuid may fail and may run out of the combinations. Am I correct or have I understood the concept wrong?

Which one is better to use? I know that shortuuid provides url friendly url(as documented on their github page)

Comment: You forgot to mention what do you want to use it for.

Comment: I was thinking of using it for comment ids for each comment on a blog. Had used uuid4 in past but came across shortuuid so was wondering which one is good and why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A UUID is just a 128-bit number. They're usually expressed in base-16, but `shortuuid` uses base-57. The UUIDs are generated with either `uuid.uuid4` or `uuid.uuid5`, so you're storing exactly the same information.

[Look at the source code](https://github.com/stochastic-technologies/shortuuid/blob/c0d01c4e423c6d0c7b53ee8f61a979f5ecda7de9/shortuuid/main.py#L32).

Comment: This is correct, a shortuuid is the same as a normal uuid, just shorter/easier to type. I'm the author of shortuuid.